# cran-r: alternative to beanplot for plotting distrubtion of trades

Tags: r

I'm  trying to reproduce a plot that I found in a paper by Carlos Drago, (slide #13). But I'm stuck. Attached is a image of the plot. I am interested in doing the right hand side plot.  I searched through Stackoverflow and was not able to find a solution. Most of the histogram questions in stack overflow  are for multiple histogram overlaying each other. In this case, it is separate histogram's rotated 90 degrees indexed by date. If possible I would like to overlay the time series (left hand side graph) on top of the right hand side graph so that they both use the left y axis.  Finally, instead of it being a histogram (which by definition gives frequency per bar), is it possible to use the actual value. That is suppose the plot was using shares traded in a one minute interval. Each bar, instead of showing the % of stock traded at that price, it would show the number of shares traded in the time interval. (That is, I guess a rotated bar chart rather than a rotated histogram)

Suggestions (or links to previous solutions) are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ggridges` might offer the functionality that you are after. Here is a slightly adjusted example using the `iris` data taken from [the `ggridges` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html).

```
library(ggridges)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) +
    geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline", bins = 20, scale = 1, draw_baseline = FALSE) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

Here is another example using some simulated data closer to your example figure.

```
# Sample data
library(zoo)
set.seed(2017)
date <- seq.POSIXt(ISOdate(2018, 7, 9), ISOdate(2018, 7, 15), by = "min")
x <- zoo(cumsum(1 + round(20 * rnorm(length(date)), 2)), date)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
```

Let's create plots similar to those in your left and right panel of your example figure.

**Left panel plot**

```
as.data.frame(x) %>%
    rownames_to_column("date") %>%
    mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(date, x)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

**Right panel plot**

```
as.data.frame(x) %>%
    rownames_to_column("date") %>%
    mutate(date = as.factor(as.Date(date))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, date)) +
    geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline", bins = 50, scale = 1, draw_baseline = FALSE) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to get the two graphs to overlay into one graph?

Comment: @patrick That's a tricky question, and should really be a new question altogether;-) I'm not sure how to do that; the x axis of the right-panel plot encodes a categorical variable, while it corresponds to a numeric variable in the left-panel plot. This might be possible by manually overlaying the plots grobs, but that will be messy.

Comment: I followed your example and it worked fine, but when I converted the code to the old fashioned way of R (it's easier for me to understand) I could not produce the 2nd graph. Could you please take a look why it fails? Thanks in advance. The code is as follows:                y<-as.data.frame(x)                               
z<-rownames_to_column(y,"date")
z1<- mutate(z,date = as.POSIXct(date)) 

ggplot(data=z1,aes(date, x)) + geom_line()
ggplot(data=z1,aes(x,date)) + geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline", bins = 50, scale = 1, draw_baseline = FALSE) +coord_flip()

Comment: @patrick *"I converted the code to the old fashioned way of R"* I have no idea what that means. Old-fashioned? Do you mean avoiding the `magrittr` pipe? Because you're stilling using non-base R functions. Either way, please take another look at my example code for panel 2. You've made a mistake when defining `z1`; it should be `z1<- mutate(z, date = as.factor(as.Date(date)))`. As explained in my previous comment, for panel 2 the x-axis encodes a categorical value (while for panel 1 it encodes a numeric variable). You can't use the same `z1` for both plots.

Comment: PS. In order for posts to be helpful to future SO readers, and to keep SO tidy and structured, it is important to close questions; please consider setting the green check mark next to the answer.